# why do we need a attribute file in sysfs directory for drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I would like to know that .. what is actually a attribute file in sysfs,..why do we need to create attribute files in sysfs directory for some drivers and not for some..

when do we actually need it ?

I have read attributes in Linux device model in LDD3 and some other tutorial sin net.. i was able to configure that it is used for communicating with device drivers from user space ... but when we can build a app for communicating with a hardware(via driver) then why do we need a extra attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

For example to avoid to write an application for every driver, or every parameter you want to set up. Just use the sysfs attribute which help you to modify driver parameter, from an application, from shell. You can retrieve useful information about the driver status. **udev** use information from sysfs.

Comment: So this means . that basically to handle a hardware from shell.. attributes can be used..

I would be really thank ful to u ,, if u gv some real example of driver in which we use attribute ..

Thanks.. Fredrico

Comment: Just explore the sysfs file system and you will see dozens of drivers sthat exports their attributes `ls /sys`. Some exaples: GPIOs, the CPU, the backlight of your screen, sensors, disks